# Generating query objects for mongoose query

Tags: mongoose

```
        const query = {}
        query['title'] = 'bogustest' //item.title
        const storedProduct = await this.ProductModel
            .findOneAndUpdate({ id: item.id }, {$set:{"title": "bogustest"}}, { upsert: true, new: true })
            .lean<MongoDB.IProductDocument>()
            .exec()
```

This works, but when I change it to:

```
        const query = {}
        query['title'] = 'bogustest' //item.title
        const storedProduct = await this.ProductModel
            .findOneAndUpdate({ id: item.id }, {$set:{query}}, { upsert: true, new: true })
            .lean<MongoDB.IProductDocument>()
            .exec()
```

It doesn't work. Is there a way to change it so that title is between quotes? I want to change 'title' to a variable called field and make it more generic, not sure why it's not working. I think I found a post on stackoverflow saying it would work, but console logging query gives me {title: 'bogustest'} instead of {'title': 'bogustest'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `{...query}`.

`{query}` is the shorthand for `{query: query}`